# Unit test onEnter with ui-router

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-ui-router

I have a state `onEnter` block like the following. I'm trying to do a redirect based on `data.length`.

```
  .state('home', {
    url: '/',
    data: {
      title: 'Home',
    },
    controller: 'HomeCtrl as home',
    templateProvider: function($templateCache) {
      return $templateCache.get('views/home.html');
    },
    onEnter: function(data, $state) {);
      if (data.length === 2) {
        $state.go('profile');
      }
    }
  });
```

How can I properly unit-test this piece of code?

Comment: what 'data' is doing in onEnter? You cannot inject a variable in onEnter.

Comment: It's an inherited resolve.